# Sinch Crashing on login

Tags: android, sinch, android-sinch-api

I moved to new Google Firebase SDK and now Sinch crashes as soon as we login.

> 07-18 22:29:24.810 20953-22666/com.ontymevalet D/Error: ERR:
>   stack=java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing
>   doInBackground()
>                                                               at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:304)
>                                                               at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
>                                                               at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
>                                                               at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
>                                                               at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
>                                                               at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
>                                                               at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
>                                                               at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
>                                                            Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of:
>   Lcom/google/android/gms/gcm/GoogleCloudMessaging;
>                                                               at com.sinch.android.rtc.internal.client.gcm.GcmTask.doInBackground(GcmTask.java:39)
>                                                               at com.sinch.android.rtc.internal.client.gcm.GcmTask.doInBackground(GcmTask.java:11)
>                                                               at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:292)
>                                                               at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
>                                                               at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231) 
>                                                               at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112) 
>                                                               at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587) 
>                                                               at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818) 
>                                                            Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class
>   "com.google.android.gms.gcm.GoogleCloudMessaging" on path:
>   DexPathList[[dex file
>   "/data/data/com.ontymevalet/files/instant-run/dex/slice-zbar_dcf0c761c9d7809b6f3862b552f4c372d226e4a4-classes.dex",
>   dex file
>   "/data/data/com.ontymevalet/files/instant-run/dex/slice-volley_adc5ba6a8ed465821b9ebab29bf6f58a861e6728-classes.dex",
>   dex file
>   "/data/data/com.ontymevalet/files/instant-run/dex/slice-support-annotations-23.1.1_f76b8af61cf9ac44a9b10306ed3c87625aa88a56-classes.dex",
>   dex file
>   "/data/data/com.ontymevalet/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_9-classes.dex",
>   dex file
>   "/data/data/com.ontymevalet/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_8-classes.dex",
>   dex file
>   "/data/data/com.ontymevalet/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_7-classes.dex",
>   dex file
>   "/data/data/com.ontymevalet/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_6-classes.dex",
>   dex file
>   "/data/data/com.ontymevalet/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_5-classes.dex",
>   dex file
>   "/data/data/com.ontymevalet/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_4-classes.dex",
>   dex file
>   "/data/data/com.ontymevalet/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_3-classes.dex",
>   dex file
>   "/data/data/com.ontymevalet/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_2-classes.dex",
>   dex file
>   "/data/data/com.ontymevalet/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_1-classes.dex",
>   dex file
>   "/data/data/com.ontymevalet/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_0-classes.dex",
>   dex file
>   "/data/data/com.ontymevalet/files/instant-run/dex/slice-sinch-android-verification-1.1.6_3c1ba98c4c929425250cfe99f037b4e268270224-classes.dex",
>   dex file
>   "/data/data/com.ontymevalet/files/instant-run/dex/slice-sinch-android-rtc-3.9.6_3e3c355364bf424dc72cfe6a3fdbcb59c941962d-classes.dex",
>   dex file
>   "/data/data/com.ontymevalet/files/instant-run/dex/slice-realm-annotations-0.90.1_70a5eda715221ffb0ac0e83ced79c37edec4dc02-classes.dex",
>   dex file
>   "/data/data/com.ontymevalet/files/instant-run/dex/slice-me.dm7.barcodescanner-zbar-1.8.4_6a183a540e8757090cbfa52996d0f10837d0cf17-classes.dex",
>   dex file
>   "/data/data/com.ontymevalet/files/instant-run/dex/slice-me.dm7.barcodescanner-core-1.8.4_dd8e1c4063ee9055c91a4cf41076f96db05e632f-classes.dex",
>   dex file
>   "/data/data/com.ontymevalet/files/instant-run/dex/slice-joda-time-2.9.2_1a5b002b1b795916c37c34dcc0f5dd4ac5a22399-classes.dex",
>   dex file
>   "/data/data/com.ontymevalet/files/instant-run/dex/slice-io.realm-realm-android-library-0.90.1_f31f3e9c34d3bd7bc8af064857a645e67c748751-classes.dex", dex file
>   "/data/data/com.ontymevalet/files/instant-run/dex/slice-io.fabric.sdk.android-fabric-1.3.10_4114ca2e2b7d1ba9e56291cc70a0412a0f9bf56f-classes.dex",
>   dex file
>   "/data/data/com.ontymevalet/files/instant-run/dex/slice-internal_impl-23.1.1_ea2cb233f5f5fc79fa6a9a193b1aca447e2c80ae-classes.dex",
>   dex file
>   "/data/data/com.ontymevalet/files/instant-run/dex/slice-de.hdodenhof-circleimageview-1.2.1_456726ca6667c251b353d7787e4f32e58be8ff17-classes.dex",
>   dex file
>   "/data/data/com.ontymevalet/files/instant-run/dex/slice-com.google.firebase-firebase-messaging-9.2.1_972daed2ef9c35b5377a18fcd3

I am using the following dependencies

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.2.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.2.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.2.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.2.1'
```

And not

```
 compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.4.0'
```

Is current Sinch SDK Version compatible with new Firebase SDK? Has anyone faced this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SInch is dependent on the GCM if you use GCM push, if you roll your own push you can for sure use firebase but we are not supporting firebase for managed push.

Comment: Thanks I understand that. What I meant was Google moved their whole Cloud Infrastructure over to Firebase including GCM. The old GCM is actually now called FCM(Firebase Cloud Messaging) and eventually GCM will retired. [FCM](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/). any plans of moving to FCM.

Comment: Yes we will support firebase going forward, dont have a time line for it yet. Can you mark my answer as answered please?

Comment: to use latest version of firebase "compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.2.6'" I have to update "compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:10.2.6'" but if I do so then it starts crashing with LinkageError. It works fine with "compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:10.0.1'" but then I can't update my firebase dependency. Any help ?